# How to change imageBackground of button onClick present in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am Developing an Application in which i want a mediabutton present in expandable headerview `ie button will do play/stop functionality.
How can i change background of button to stop background when song is played and change it to play background when it is stopped.
I am also facing a problem when i want a song should be stopped and its background changed to play when next song on expandable listview is present.

[image]

And My Source Code is  :::

In Expandable listview  i had done

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_row, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.medicineName);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        final ImageView playpause = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.actionPlaypause);


        playpause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ///custom trick
                v.setTag(orignalMedName);

                mybtnListen.ListenToBtn(headerTitle, v);

            }
        });

        if (groupPosition % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BBEBFF"));

        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

in my activity which is implementing this view

```
case R.id.actionPlaypause:

            final ImageView actionPlPause = (ImageView) bt
                    .findViewById(R.id.actionPlaypause);

            // previmg.add(actionPlPause);

            Log.d("currentid", "" + actionPlPause.getId());

            Uri myUri;
            DatabaseHandler dbcheck = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

            Log.d("mediacheck", "" + "media is playing");

            // actionPlPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);

            boolean recordCheck = dbcheck.checkSinlgeEntry(
                    DatabaseHandler.TABLE_MEDICINERECORD, medicineName);

            if (recordCheck) {
                myUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/SaySong/USaRecord/" + medicineName
                        + ".mp3"); // initialize Uri here

            } else {
                myUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/SaySong/USaRecord/"
                        + medicineName + ".mp3"); // initialize Uri here

            }

            // mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                // mediaPlayer.start();
                actionPlPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);

                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {

                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getActivity(), myUri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                    SaveInRecentStore(medicineName);

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.i("Completion Listener", "Song Complete");

                        Log.d("mediacheck", "" + "media playing finished");

                        actionPlPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                        // mp.release();

                    }
                });

            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                actionPlPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Background of the Button onClick:

```
playpause.setBackgroundRessource(R.drawable.yourBackground)
```

Thats it

Comment: Buddy its not that much simple...just read the highlighted image ?  first read question and then answer it.....!! Don`t just waste precious time of dev...